# Where to modify $cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique']?

Tags: configuration, phpmyadmin, xampp

I wanted to set $cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique'] to TRUE so that I can edit the datas in **phpMyAdmin** without any Primary Keys present, but after checking over **config.inc.php** and both **layout.inc.php** in **phpmyadmin/themes/**

I can't find the mentioned configuration.

Does anyone know how where can I modify **$cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique']** ?

Currently **using phpMyAdmin via XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2.**

Answer (score 2):

There are default directives, and you only need to put something in `config.inc.php` if you are changing from the default. In fact, the official phpMyAdmin distribution doesn't come with a `config.inc.php` at all; if you need to change some value you have to create the file yourself. Since you're trying to change a setting that doesn't already exist in your configuration, you simply have to add it to `config.inc.php`. Just find a good section, anywhere will do really (I like to keep it near the top so it's visually separated from the server-specific settings), and add the complete line like `$cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique'] = true;`

Save the file, logout and log back in so the changes are loaded, and you should be all set.

You can see more information in the [phpMyAdmin manual](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manually-creating-the-file).

Answer (score 2):

Just open XAMPP and click on "Config" in the Apache module. Then select "phpMyAdmin (config.inc.php)".

Don't forget to set the semicolon ';' at the end of the variable.

```
$cfg['RowActionLinksWithoutUnique'] = true;
```

[image: configuration]